# Once thought impossible

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to recall coming across a word for things that were once thought to be impossible. I just can't remember what it was. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest 'inconceivable'.

Here's my example:

"Commercial air-travel was *inconceivable* in the time of Alfred the Great. Now we can not only conceive of it, we can even take part."

Answer (score 1):

**Magic.**  "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."  Arthur C. Clarke.   See Clarke's three laws at Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.  There are antecedents to Clarke's formulation.